# Ember Sign-up CreateUser not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, ember.js, firebase-authentication, torii

I am trying to create a user on ember with Firebase for the backend. Here is my code on my sign-up controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({  
  firebase: Ember.inject.service(),
  actions: {
    signUp() {
        let controller = this;
        var email = this.get('email');
        var password = this.get('password');
        this.get('firebase').createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            console.log(errorCode);
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log(errorMessage);
        });
    }
  }
});
```

currently getting the error that createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not a function[Here is a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgFae.png)
Thank you.

Comment: try this this.get('firebase').auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword`

Comment: @kumkanillam I am now getting the error that ' this.get(...).auth is not a function'

Comment: You may try `firebaseApp: Ember.inject.service(),`  and then `this.get('firebaseApp').auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(`

Comment: @kumkanillam "TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined" code is: '     this.get('firebaseApp').auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
'